# AngularJs, ngRepeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJs. I am displaying google maps with markers. After clicking marker I am displaying clicked marker details.

Here is my `Controller.js`

```
  function createMarker(latitude,longitude,name,address,locationId,sid){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
        title: name
        });
       $scope.leadsForMap=[];
       $scope.location={};
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       $scope.location = {
                name: name,
                sid: sid,
                address: address,
                locationId:locationId
                };
       $scope.leadsForMap.push($scope.location);
       $scope.markers.push(marker);
   }
```

In html I am trying to loop `$scope.leadsForMap` array and display particular details after click like this

html

```
    <div  data-ng-repeat="location in leadsForMap track by $index" data-ng-
    if="leadsForMap.length>0">
    {{$index+1}} {{location.name}} - {{location.sid}},{{location.address}}
    </div>
```

But this div is not at all displaying even if `$scope.leadsForMap` has value. Can anyone tell where it is wrong?

Comment: ok this is wrong if="$scope.leadsForMap>0" its data-ng-if="leadsForMap.length>0"

Comment: Sorry .I updated my question

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: use above div {{leadsForMap}} to check if your model is the correct one if it is corrent i cant find a reason to not showing up in ng-repeat

Comment: I checked but it is displaying empty array [].But if i put console for $scope.leadsForMap in controller.js it is displaying values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
$scope.$apply()
```

One has to use `$scope.$apply` when event is out of scope of angular and angular will not run digest cycle as it is out of scope.

You need to run the digest cycle which is going to run manually by    $scope.$apply()

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       $scope.location = {
             name: name,
             sid: sid,
             address: address,
             locationId:locationId
       };
       $scope.leadsForMap.push($scope.location);
       $scope.markers.push(marker);
       $scope.$apply();
}
```

Check [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide:-When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

Comment: I added $scope.apply but is displaying this error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress.And div still is not showing

Comment: if(!$scope.$$phase) {
       $scope.$apply();
}

Comment: Can you try this?

Comment: yeah i added but still div is not showing up.Error is gone but still html div not showing

Comment: I placed if(!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }  after $scope.leadsForMap.push($scope.location); means before $scope.markers.push(marker);.It worked.Thank you very much